# What is the correct adjective that describes the temporal proximity between the two events?

Tags: adjectives, british-english, time

I'm trying to find the best adjective to describe the temporal proximity between the two events: the creation of two WiFi networks.

Currently I'm using *almost concurrent* to describe the proximity:

> But it is not possible to prevent all the **almost-concurrent** requests because some of them are asynchronous."*

But it sounds not very good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *almost concurrent* is easily understood (but I would not hyphenate it). You might also consider ***virtually*** concurrent.

The term *[concurrent](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/concurrent)* may suggest some degree of cooperation or coordination. You might consider **[simultaneous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/simultaneous)** instead which describes timing without implying any other relationships. You could similarly use *almost simultaneous* or *virtually simultaneous*.

The adverb *nearly* could also be used with either.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer:

You can use *near-simultaneous* and it is quite common in technical contexts. *[Near-](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/near_3)* is a common prefix and means "almost".

Here is a usage similar to your context:

> Servers are by definition shared devices, and their performance is most often measured in relation to how well they accommodate multiple, **near-simultaneous requests** for service.
>
> <sub>*[Communications and Networking for the IBM PC & Compatibles](https://books.google.es/books?id=2jcsAAAAIAAJ&q=%22near-simultaneous%20requests%22%20network&dq=%22near-simultaneous%20requests%22%20network&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjByOL55sv4AhWyVPEDHQQwDV4Q6AF6BAgJEAI)* - Larry E. Jordan, Bruce Churchill</sub>